# The color of the triangle mesh is affected after I call the function SetScalars

Tags: colors, rendering, mesh, vtk

I read one triangle mesh file from the disk. The mesh itself contains color
information. I can render the mesh correctly.  The color of rendered mesh
is from the color information of the mesh. To use the scalars, I call the
function SetScalars.  The color of the rendered mesh is changed and now the
color is from scalars. However I hope to use the color of the mesh. I can
find the answer from the internet. Can anyone help me?

Regards
Jogging Song

Answer (score 1):

Why not add the new array with AddArray() rather than SetScalars(). You can also use SelectColorArray() method found in the mapper. See [this](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkMapper.html#a10824f74bc63bb68c6e39fc50eb49023) and [this](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/VisualizationAlgorithms/TubesWithVaryingRadiusAndColors).